# Word displays "Failed to Upload" message when saving using ITHit Server dll

Tags: webdav, ithit-webdav-server

Based on our testing the issue (Failed to Upload) seems to happen after the lock timer is expired. The document can be saved many times before the timer expires but once the lock time is exceeded, if the user attempts to Save a word document, a yellow Failed to Upload bar is displayed.

We have set the lock timer to be the current system time plus the lock time that Word is requesting (3600 seconds).

```
Timeout: Second-3600
```

Word is trying to issue a Lock and getting the 500 error as the result:

```
LOCK http://t430-dev10/TMS_71/Edit_WebDAV/000%20TEST%20ADD.doc HTTP/1.1
```

And getting a response of HTTP/1.1 500 Internal server error:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at dn.i(IHierarchyItem A_0, DavContextBase A_1)
at dn.ProcessRequest(DavContextBase context, IHierarchyItem item)
at ITHit.WebDAV.Server.DavEngine.Run(DavContextBase context)

X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Engine: IT Hit WebDAV Server .Net v3.7.1780.0
```

We have also tried v3.9.2111 with the same results.

Base on that I'd like some advice on how to save the document after the lock timer expires. Also, can the lock extended so that the Save will upload the file? And/or can the server engine be fixed to allow the file upload?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to save the document after the lock timer expires?  Can the lock extended so that the Save will upload the file?  Can the server engine be fixed to allow the file upload?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this issue is caused by returning *null* from DavContextBase.[GetHierarchyItem](http://doc3.webdavsystem.com/ITHit.WebDAV.Server.DavContextBase.GetHierarchyItem.html) implementation. The item returned from GetHierarchyItem in LOCK request must also implement ILock interface.

Also note that after initial lock, MS Office is refreshing the lock from time to time, sending a new lock time, so the lock should not expire until the MS Office application is open. The Engine calls ILock.[RefreshLock](http://doc3.webdavsystem.com/ITHit.WebDAV.Server.Class2.ILock.RefreshLock.html) when MS Office refreshes the lock.

Comment: In reviewing the code snippet for RefreshLock() from the link provided, there is a function call near the end of RefreshLock....saveLock()...  I noticed it is also called in the Lock() and UnLock() functions on the web site.  what does it do?  where can I get a copy of it?